# C enum array (need help understanding)

Tags: c, arrays, loops, enums

```
enum cell_contents {
    INVALID, HOLE, PEG
};

static const enum cell_contents master_board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH] = {
    { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID },
    { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID },
    { PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG },
    { PEG, PEG, PEG, HOLE, PEG, PEG, PEG },
    { PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG },
    { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID },
    { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID }
};
```

I need assistance on how to loop through the master_board table and determine whether the field is INVALID, PEG or HOLE.

I tried using this method, which didn't work:

```
char *characters[] = {"\t", 'o', '.'};

/* display the game board to the screen */
void display_board(enum cell_contents board[][BOARD_HEIGHT])
{
    /* delete this comment and write your own comments and code here */
    for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++) {
        printf("%d.", i+1);

        int length = sizeof(board[i]) / sizeof(board[i][0]);
        printf("Length: %d", length);

        for(int e = 0; e < length; e++){
            if(board[i][e] == INVALID)
                printf("\t%c", characters[0]);
            else if(board[i][e] == PEG)
                printf("\t%c", characters[1]);
            else if(board[i][e] == HOLE)
                printf("\t%c", characters[2]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I am using another function to call display_board:

```
void play_game(void)
{
    enum cell_contents board[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
    init_board(board);
    /* delete this comment and write your own comments and code here */

    //while(!is_game_over(board)) {
        display_board(board);
    //}
}
```

BOARD_WIDTH & BOARD_HEIGHT are the same at 7.

Comment: Your parameter definition is wrong (you're using BOARD_HEIGHT as the 2nd array bound as your "y" but in definition you're using it as your x), also consider `enum cell_contents **board` since it will be truncated by the compiler anyway.  And, FYI: You could just use `board[i][e]` as index for `characters` since it matches it anyway (board[i][e] can either be `INVALID/PEG/HOLE` and those are `0/1/2` so...

Comment: Might you want `void display_board(enum cell_contents board[][BOARD_WIDTH])`?

Comment: It looks like `BOARD_WIDTH == BOARD_HEIGHT` (and both are 7), but the point @chux makes is correct for consistency.

Comment: You say "Doesn't work", but you don't say how it doesn't work.  Please be a lot more explicit.  Note that using `'\t'` for invalid is probably a bad idea; use a regular printing character such as `x`.  I don't entirely trust the tabs in the printing in the loop, but if you use an `x` (or an `@` or any other regular printable character), you should be better off.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Suspect the problem is in the initialization or use of the, unposted, `master_board`.  Need to see upper level code.

Comment: Looks like I am not initializing the board correctly. Updated the code above to show which function I'm using to send the arguments across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define BOARD_WIDTH and BOARD_HEIGHT ?
This code works for me:

```
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 7
#define BOARD_WIDTH 7
enum cell_contents {
  INVALID, HOLE, PEG
};

static const enum cell_contents master_board[BOARD_HEIGHT][BOARD_WIDTH] = {
  { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID },
  { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID },
  { PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG },
  { PEG, PEG, PEG, HOLE, PEG, PEG, PEG },
  { PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG, PEG },
  { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID },
  { INVALID, INVALID, PEG, PEG, PEG, INVALID, INVALID }
};

char *characters[] = {"\t", 'o', '.'};


void display_board(enum cell_contents board[][BOARD_HEIGHT])
{
    /* delete this comment and write your own comments and code here */
   for(int i = 0; i < BOARD_HEIGHT; i++) {
      printf("%d.", i+1);

      int length = sizeof(board[i]) / sizeof(board[i][0]);
      printf("Length: %d", length);

      for(int e = 0; e < length; e++){
          if(board[i][e] == INVALID)
              printf("\t%c", characters[0]);
          else if(board[i][e] == PEG)
              printf("\t%c", characters[1]);
          else if(board[i][e] == HOLE)
              printf("\t%c", characters[2]);
      }

       printf("\n");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
 display_board(master_board);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am using another function to display the board:void play_game(void)
{
 enum cell_contents board[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
 init_board(board);
 /* delete this comment and write your own comments and code here */

 //while(!is_game_over(board)) {
  display_board(board);
 //}
}

Comment: I wasn't initialising the variable properly. The use of memcpy(board, master_board, sizeof(master_board)); worked!